# Go function syntax explanation

Tags: go

I am reading one book.

One function came out:

> func (ip IP) DefaultMask() IPMask

Source code for this function is located inside the net package:

```
func (ip IP) DefaultMask() IPMask {
    if ip = ip.To4(); ip == nil {
        return nil
    }
    switch true {
    case ip[0] < 0x80:
        return classAMask
    case ip[0] < 0xC0:
        return classBMask
    default:
        return classCMask
    }
}
```

Question is: what is `(ip IP)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax allows you to call DefaultMask() from an IP type, similar to how member functions work in other languages:

```
ip.DefaultMask()
```

The (ip IP) basically represents the "thiscall" argument.

Answer (score 1):

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations

"Method declarations" - the way to define a method for receiver base type.